# Want to Overlay an Image on top of many instanced object in a grid

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, image, instances

I am trying to recreate the intro to the show Ted Lasso, and ran into a problem.[image: wanted result]

When trying to overlay this image:

[image]

overtop my seating configuration, I only get a blue color on the seats. The seats are set up as instances based on the stands, using geometry nodes

[image: geo_nodes]

The image I am trying to overlay treats each seat as a pixel and is 133x120. I was wondering if anyone knew of an easy way to get this done. The seats are laid out uniformly with a set offset:

[image: specific seating]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, and I am very not sure, that your problem is to set properly your image coordinates.
May be you can do it like that:

[image]

I hope it help.

[image]